# Django problems loading static files

Tags: javascript, django, static

I am trying to add external JS file to my Django project. Unfortunately it doesn't work while I am trying to add it in many ways:

1. In my template.html I have specified direct path:

   {% load static %}

   < script> src="{% static 'commerce/static/js/test.js' %}" < /script>

it doesn't work.

2. My settings.py file:

   BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**)))

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
   ]

my layout.hmtl:

```
{% load static %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/test.js' %}"></script>
```

Depending on sources combination, I receive various output in terminal regarding status of loaded files:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5167
 "GET /static/js/test.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0

 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5167
 "GET /static/js/test.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 

 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5167
 "GET /static/js/test.js HTTP/1.1" 404 0
```

Even if my 'test.js' is loaded correctly (HTTP status 200 or sometimes no information regarding test.js load status), my javascript functions doesn't work.

In order to check if other static files are loaded I even tried to remove my CSS file from static folder and surprisingly (or not), after re-running my app it is still formatted. Although I left source for CSS unchanged in my layout.html:

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Summarizing:

- I cannot manage to add external *.js file to my Django app,
- Even if source of *.js file is correct and Django loads it, javascript functions doesn't work
- While I remove my *.css file from the source path, my Django app is still correctly formatted (?!)
- I keep one more copy of the same app on my disk but in separate directory

Can you please point where am I mistaken? I am running out of ideas now.

Comment: @kiviak Thank you for answering. Yes for sure they are correct - if I put them directly into layout.html everything works fine.